# Recurrence Tree for Recurrence Inequality

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I'm used to solving recurrences that are in the form of T(n) = ...

However, when analyzing an algorithm, its recurrence form is:

$$ T(n) < \sqrt{n} \cdot T(\sqrt{n}) + n $$

How do I solve a recurrence with an inequality?

Comment: Inequalities can always be essentially sharp, i.e. maybe you only subtract $1$ for each discrete case when you apply the recursive inequality. So you may as well assume equality and solve the recurrence, and then state your final answer in big-O notation to indicate that the true answer may be asymptotically less, depending on how much slack there is in the inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

Just like the equality case. In the present case, note that $T(n)/n\lt T(\sqrt{n})/\sqrt{n}+1$. Let $S(k)=T(2^{2^k})/2^{2^k}$, then $S(k)\lt S(k-1)+1$ hence $S(k)\lt S(0)+k$ for every $k$, and $T(2^{2^k})\lt2^{2^k}(T(2)/2+k)$, which you will probably want to transform into 
$$
T(n)\lt n\cdot(\log_2\log_2(n)+c).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that your recurrence relation will keep getting you one copy of $n$ every time you apply it recursively, until finally you get that taking $k$ square-roots of $n$ reduces you to the base case. Each time you take a square-root recursively, it reduces the log by a factor of two. So you are really dividing the log by 2 until you get to the base case. It will take $O(\log \log n)$ iterations to do this. This means that you will have $T(n) = O(n \log \log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $H(n)=\sqrt n H(\sqrt n)+n$ and solve that, then (with appropriately chosen base cases) you can prove by induction that $T(n)<H(n)$. This is the best you can do, since the difference between the sides of your original inequality can be arbitrarily small.